# How to automate running the dhclient in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I need to run `sudo dhclient eth0` *every time*  I unplug and plug  the Ethernet back in.

This is pretty annoying! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check your network configuration in:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

If you want DHCP, it should be something like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you want a static IP, it should go like below:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You can [read this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html) too.