# How to automate running the dhclient for wwan0?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, dhcp

in Linux Mint 17 I have to run `sudo dhclient` every time I connect and disconnect to/from the Internet using a mobile broadband dongle, because otherwise the connection is declared active but when I try to open a web page my browsers freeze in the "resolving host" state (and the email client too).

I thought the problem was very similar to the one mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/151936/how-to-automate-running-the-dhclient-in-ubuntu), so I edited "/etc/network/interfaces" adding the last two lines:

`# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wwan0
iface wwan0 inet dhcp`

then I also run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` but nothing changes (I rather get these messages: "Waiting for network configuration...", "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...", "Booting system without full network configuration...").

How should I proceed? Thanks a lot.